# Capitalization of job title

Tags: capitalization

Would you capitalize the job title in the following sentence?

> I am writing this letter in regard to Joe Brown who is applying for the director of teaching and learning position in the XYZ School District.

Answer (score 4):

The Chicago Manual of Style says not to capitalize a title when it appears alone like that. Nor should you cap it when it appears in apposition, such as (if your candidate gets the job),

> Joe Brown, director of teaching and learning

You cap formal titles when they appear before someone's name,

> Director Joe Brown

though not every title is meant to be used in that way... for instance, if you were talking about Steven Spielberg, in most contexts you would say

> director Steven Spielberg

because in most contexts you wouldn't be ascribing a formal title to him, but merely describing what he does.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that when a title immediately precedes the name, e.g. "Director Joe Brown," then the job title is capitalized, but not when it comes afterwards.  See, e.g., GPO Style Manual § 3.34.  Exceptions are made for especially important positions like President of the United States or Queen of England.  Ibid. § 3.35.  The GPO Style Manual gives the example:  "Charles F. Hughes, rear admiral, U.S. Navy: the rear admiral."  In your sentence, Mr. Brown doesn't even have the job, so director would be lower case.