# When do you capitalize professions?

Tags: grammaticality

For example:

> Detective Jones

I think the *D* in *Detective Jones* should always be capitalized, because I believe that is the norm.

But what if, after introducing Detective Jones, I later refer to him as *The Detective*. For example:

> Detective Jones asked me a few question, which I answered. After
>   listening carefully and taking notes, the Detective then came back to
>   me with some more questions.

I think you would capitalize the *D*, because *"the Detective"* is being used as a shorthand for *"Detective Jones"*. But it looks a little odd, so I am not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding U.S. President capitalization](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44848/understanding-u-s-president-capitalization). (Actually, [Proper capitalization of titles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162939/proper-capitalization-of-titles/163070#163070) is a better fit, but was closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: The standard principle is you capitalise when it's a proper noun, not when it's generic. Ignoring quirky usages like *the Donald*, that's not applicable when writing about *what **the** detective did*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Capitalization of job title](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107156/capitalization-of-job-title)*. Yet another possibility is *[Should “Project Manager” be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1393)*